# How to put the Y-axis of a chart to the right-side of it

Tags: javascript, charts

I created a chart in Billboard.js which looks like this:

```
var chart = bb.generate({
    "data": {
        "type": "line",
        "x": "x",
        "columns": columns
    },
    "point": {
        "show": false
    },
    "legend": {
        "show": false
    },
    "axis": {
        "x": {
            "localtime": false,
            "type": "timeseries",
            "tick": {
                count: 7,
                "format": "%b %d, %Y",
                "rotate": 45,
                "multiline": true
            },
             "label": {
                "text": label,
                "position": "outer-center"
            },
        },
        "y": {
            "label": {
                "text": "Energy (kWh)",
                "position": "outer-middle"
            },
        },
    },
    "bindto": "#main-chart"
});
```

Now it looks like the classic style, X axis on the bottom and Y axis on the left. I want to move the Y axis on the right of the table.

I've tried many ways to do it but without success like these ones:

-changing its name from `y` to `y2`

-adding the same code but with `y2`:

```
"y": {
    "label": {
    "text": "Energy (kWh)",
        "position": "outer-middle"
    },
},

"y2": {
    "label": {
        "text": "Energy (kWh)",
        "position": "outer-middle"
    },
},
```

I addied `show` attribute inside the label like this:

```
"y": {
    "label": {
        "show": false,
        "text": "Energy (kWh)",
        "position": "outer-middle"
    },
},
"y2": {
    "label": {
        "show": true,
        "text": "Energy (kWh)",
        "position": "outer-middle"
    },
},
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, @Nouphal pointed exactly what to do.
The key point is set `data.axes` options to bound datas to `y2` axis.

- https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/release/latest/doc/Options.html#.data:axes

I made working demo with your code(except the data value), so replace it setting with your data and will work.

```js
var chart = bb.generate({
    "data": {
        "type": "line",
        "x": "x",
        "columns": [
          // replace with your data value
          ['x', '2017-10-01', '2017-10-02', '2017-10-03', '2017-10-04', '2017-10-05', '2017-10-06'],
          ["data1", 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
          ["data2", 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
        ],
        "axes": {
          "data1": "y2",
          "data2": "y2"
        }
    },
    "point": {
        "show": false
    },
    "legend": {
        "show": false
    },
    "axis": {
        "x": {
            "localtime": false,
            "type": "timeseries",
            "tick": {
                count: 7,
                "format": "%b %d, %Y",
                "rotate": 45,
                "multiline": true
            },
             "label": {
                "text": "label",
                "position": "outer-center"
            },
        },
        "y": {
          "show": false
        },
        "y2": {
            "show": true,
            "label": {
                "text": "Energy (kWh)",
                "position": "outer-middle"
            },
        },
    },
    "bindto": "#main-chart"
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/billboard.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/billboard.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main-chart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have problems when I try to use my data. In my case `columns` is an array which can have a variable number of elements. For example, one case can be like this: https://i.imgur.com/4L2r609.png Do you have an idea about how to import this array there?

Comment: If you could provide the real data that you need to handle, will facilitate find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var chart = bb.generate({
  "data": {
    "columns": [
    ["data1", 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
    ["data2", 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
    ],
    "axes": {
      "data1": "y2" // set additional y axis
    }
  },
  "axis": {
    "y": {
      "show": false // hide default y axis
    },
    "y2": {
      "show": true
    }
  },
  "bindto": "#AdditionalYAxis"
});
```

I have tried it on their demo from github. There is an option `axis` where you can simply hide the axis. Hope this helps.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/k3o1ws47/

Comment: this is using hardcoded data. isn't it possible to use my chart's data?